# JS OO basics and why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, oop

Aparently I fail to understand how to use simple OO patterns in JS. Hopefully someone can just give me a hint where I am going wrong.

Here is a short test. When loaded into a browser the development console shows two things:

1. `undefined` as value of `Element.Display` and
2. an obviously failed assignment to `Board.Display` because of this

Interesting detail: the debug output of `Element` *does* contain `Display`...

My question: why doesn't this work?

---

File "test.html":

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```

File "test.js":

```
Element: {
    Display = function() {
        // declare something
        // do something
    } // Element.Display
}; // Element

var Board = function() {
    // debug output
    console.log(Element);
    console.log(Element.Display);
    // declare something
    Display: new Element.Display();
    // do domething
}();
```

---

The above example at jsfiddle.net: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8vZNV/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Element:` is a *label*.

You want to assign an object to a variable:

`Element =`

You should declare the variable first though.

`var Element =`

---

Then we have this.

```
Display = function() {
    // declare something
    // do something
} // Element.Display
```

Before you fix the last problem, it is valid (because it is a function assignment to a global inside a block).

After you fix that problem it becomes an error.

Use `:` between property names and property values inside an object literal.

---

The second half of your code has problems too.

```
var Board = function() {
    // Also a label
    Display: new Element.Display();

    // there is no return statement in this function
    // so you are assigning undefined to Board
}();
```

Comment: Also, note that "Display = function() {" inside the Element "object" doesnt work

Comment: OK, I actually tried numerous variations of course before posting here. The declaration with `var` was amonst those. But ok, let's see. Currently I get a syntax error when declaring like this: `var Element = {`, or should it be `var Element = function(){`?

Comment: @arkascha — Depends if you want an object or a function. `var Element = {` isn't a syntax error. What follows it might be.

Comment: @arkascha — That error, as pointed out by cernunnos, is covered in the middle portion of this answer.

Comment: Ok, I just got rid of the error, but I don't knwo why :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to "update()"... Ok things seem to work now, so thanks. I could have sworn I tried this combination too (amongst the millions of attempts I did), but obviously I am wrong in that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could help clarify things a little:

Element is declared as an **object** with a function named 'Display'.

```
var Element = {
    Display : function() {
        console.log('display something');
    } 
};
```

Board is declared as a **function** that calls the Display function of the Element object.

```
var Board = function() {        
    return Element.Display();       
}();
```